# USB drive doesn't show up in directory tree until opened in Nautilus

Tags: mount, nautilus, usb-drive

I have a particular USB stick that I routinely use for file transfer.  When plugged in, it eventually gets mounted at `/media/user/Transfer`.  I say "eventually" because, at first, my shell tells me that `/media/user` is empty (`mount` also fails to show the device).  Only when I open the drive in Nautilus does it then show up in the shell (and under `mount`).

This is the consistent behavior and so it doesn't appear to be merely a timing issue.  What could be causing this?

This is on Ubuntu 20.04.

The output of `dpkg -l | grep mount` is

```
ii libmount-dev:amd64    2.34-0.1ubuntu9.3    amd64    device mounting library - headers and static libraries
ii libmount1:amd64       2.34-0.1ubuntu9.3    amd64    device mounting library
ii libmount1:i386        2.34-0.1ubuntu9.3    i386     device mounting library
ii mount                 2.34-0.1ubuntu9.3    amd64    tools for mounting and manipulating filesystems
```

`/etc/fstab` contains

```
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root   /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0    1
UUID=54DF-0F1C              /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077        0    1
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1 none            swap    sw                0    1
```

The output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount` is

```
true
```

When inserting the USB drive, the output from `udisksctl monitor` is

```
14:19:28.156: Added /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/Verbatim_STORE_N_GO_071816855864FE27
  org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive:
    CanPowerOff:                true
    Configuration:              {}
    ConnectionBus:              usb
    Ejectable:                  true
    Id:                         Verbatim-STORE-N-GO-071816855864FE27
    Media:                      
    MediaAvailable:             true
    MediaChangeDetected:        true
    MediaCompatibility:         
    MediaRemovable:             true
    Model:                      STORE N GO
    Optical:                    false
    OpticalBlank:               false
    OpticalNumAudioTracks:      0
    OpticalNumDataTracks:       0
    OpticalNumSessions:         0
    OpticalNumTracks:           0
    Removable:                  true
    Revision:                   PMAP
    RotationRate:               -1
    Seat:                       seat0
    Serial:                     071816855864FE27
    SiblingId:                  /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0
    Size:                       31042043904
    SortKey:                    01hotplug/1655835568155716
    TimeDetected:               1655835568155716
    TimeMediaDetected:          1655835568155716
    Vendor:                     Verbatim
    WWN:                        
14:19:28.156: Added /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb
  org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block:
    Configuration:              []
    CryptoBackingDevice:        '/'
    Device:                     /dev/sdb
    DeviceNumber:               2064
    Drive:                      '/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/Verbatim_STORE_N_GO_071816855864FE27'
    HintAuto:                   true
    HintIconName:               
    HintIgnore:                 false
    HintName:                   
    HintPartitionable:          true
    HintSymbolicIconName:       
    HintSystem:                 false
    Id:                         
    IdLabel:                    
    IdType:                     
    IdUUID:                     
    IdUsage:                    
    IdVersion:                  
    MDRaid:                     '/'
    MDRaidMember:               '/'
    PreferredDevice:            /dev/sdb
    ReadOnly:                   false
    Size:                       31042043904
    Symlinks:                   /dev/disk/by-id/usb-Verbatim_STORE_N_GO_071816855864FE27-0:0
                                /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
    UserspaceMountOptions:      
  org.freedesktop.UDisks2.PartitionTable:
    Partitions:         []
    Type:               gpt
14:19:28.332: Added /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb1
  org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Block:
    Configuration:              []
    CryptoBackingDevice:        '/'
    Device:                     /dev/sdb1
    DeviceNumber:               2065
    Drive:                      '/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/Verbatim_STORE_N_GO_071816855864FE27'
    HintAuto:                   true
    HintIconName:               
    HintIgnore:                 false
    HintName:                   
    HintPartitionable:          true
    HintSymbolicIconName:       
    HintSystem:                 false
    Id:                         by-uuid-6294ed84-5993-4b8e-a286-03716e760716
    IdLabel:                    Transfer
    IdType:                     ext4
    IdUUID:                     6294ed84-5993-4b8e-a286-03716e760716
    IdUsage:                    filesystem
    IdVersion:                  1.0
    MDRaid:                     '/'
    MDRaidMember:               '/'
    PreferredDevice:            /dev/sdb1
    ReadOnly:                   false
    Size:                       31039946752
    Symlinks:                   /dev/disk/by-id/usb-Verbatim_STORE_N_GO_071816855864FE27-0:0-part1
                                /dev/disk/by-label/Transfer
                                /dev/disk/by-partuuid/bd0549e1-a5e5-47e5-8390-be12eac7ea88
                                /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:1:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1
                                /dev/disk/by-uuid/6294ed84-5993-4b8e-a286-03716e760716
    UserspaceMountOptions:      
  org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Filesystem:
    MountPoints:        
    Size:               31039946752
  org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Partition:
    Flags:              0
    IsContained:        false
    IsContainer:        false
    Name:               
    Number:             1
    Offset:             1048576
    Size:               31039946752
    Table:              '/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb'
    Type:               0fc63daf-8483-4772-8e79-3d69d8477de4
    UUID:               bd0549e1-a5e5-47e5-8390-be12eac7ea88
14:19:28.333: /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb: org.freedesktop.UDisks2.PartitionTable: Properties Changed
  Partitions:           ['/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdb1']
```

and the output from `journalctl -f` is

```
Jun 21 14:19:25 napalmshoes kernel: usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 91 using xhci_hcd
Jun 21 14:19:25 napalmshoes kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=18a5, idProduct=0302, bcdDevice= 1.00
Jun 21 14:19:25 napalmshoes kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun 21 14:19:25 napalmshoes kernel: usb 1-1: Product: STORE N GO
Jun 21 14:19:25 napalmshoes kernel: usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Verbatim
Jun 21 14:19:25 napalmshoes kernel: usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 071816855864FE27
Jun 21 14:19:25 napalmshoes kernel: usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Jun 21 14:19:25 napalmshoes kernel: scsi host4: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
Jun 21 14:19:25 napalmshoes mtp-probe[3425657]: checking bus 1, device 91: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1"
Jun 21 14:19:25 napalmshoes mtp-probe[3425657]: bus: 1, device: 91 was not an MTP device
Jun 21 14:19:25 napalmshoes mtp-probe[3425664]: checking bus 1, device 91: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1"
Jun 21 14:19:25 napalmshoes mtp-probe[3425664]: bus: 1, device: 91 was not an MTP device
Jun 21 14:19:27 napalmshoes kernel: scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Verbatim STORE N GO       PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
Jun 21 14:19:27 napalmshoes kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
Jun 21 14:19:27 napalmshoes kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 60628992 512-byte logical blocks: (31.0 GB/28.9 GiB)
Jun 21 14:19:27 napalmshoes kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Jun 21 14:19:27 napalmshoes kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
Jun 21 14:19:27 napalmshoes kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
Jun 21 14:19:27 napalmshoes kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
Jun 21 14:19:27 napalmshoes kernel:  sdb: sdb1
Jun 21 14:19:27 napalmshoes kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Comment: please [edit] your question and show us `dpkg -l | grep mount` and `cat /etc/fstab` also `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount`

Comment: Non of this in your case remove your usb stick `udisksctl monitor` and `journalctl -f` connect your stick. Did you wrote some kind of own udev-rule?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  This is a work computer.

Comment: Okay please show the output from my 2 last command after you put your stick in.

Comment: Now I know what it is not. One last thought. Please create `/etc/modprobe.d/uas.conf` important is only suffix .conf content `options usb-storage quirks=18a5:0302:u` this will block module uas to load for this usb stick. I have also one that do not like uas.

Comment: Done.  No change in behavior.

Comment: sorry out of knowledge.

Comment: All right.  I really appreciate the effort.